# Is it possible to go through documents in cloud firestore to see if a value of a property is equal to a comparing one?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have website written in plain javascript to keep daily to-do tasks and the app crashed lately because different tasks of the same date was created on accident.  My question is...

- how can i write an if statement that checks if a document from a collection has a property (in my case the date) that is equal to the one in the input field of my form.  i guess it should check after i click submit?  if it exists, creation should be denyed, if not, ok to proceed.

i am using cloud firestore by the way...  many thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you asking how to [perform queries with Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make a query to get a document that has same date:

```
  var query = db.collection("yourCollectionName").where("date", "==", dateInInputfield);

  query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
       if (querySnapshot.empty) {
         //empty
       } else {
        // not empty
       }
   });
```

If empty{you can proceed}, if notEmpty{some other task already exist on same date}

If you are making an app like this, a cleaner approach will be to name the id of a document as it's date, for eg. if a task is created at timestamp of 1234567, create a document named 1234567 and inside it, store all the necessary information.

By following this approach, if you create a new task, simply fetch a document by the name in inputfield,

```
   var docRef = db.collection("yourCollectionName").doc("date");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
             //this means some other document already exists
  } else {
             //safe to create a new document by this date.
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

Comment: i dont think i will be renaming the ids for now.  but i find your first approach quite helpful.  wait so how exactly i do check if the query is empty or not?  i mean the code for it, thanks!!!

Comment: @UweWong, I've edited the answer to include that code.

Comment: @UweWong, thanks. If it worked, click that tick and accept the answer, so it'll be helpful for others.

Comment: alright clicked.  i also need help with deleting stuff from firestore if you have time to take a peek over there in my other post.  thanks!